# React code not getting invoked - Basics of React

Tags: reactjs

The div id on line 9 is not getting invoked.
The output does not show the text invoked under the reactDom.render function. It only prints only the "Hello World from the index form within the HTML" on line 10. What am I missing ???
Using the express web server to run.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/6.1.19/browser.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello world from the index</h1>
    <div id="app1"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">
      ReactDOM.render(
        <h1>HELLLLLOO</h1>,
        document.getElementById('app1')
      );
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use `ReactDOM.render(` instead of `ReactDom.render(`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri it still does not work

Comment: Your CDNs timeout. Use different cdn link. Also use babel-standalone instead of babel-core

Comment: yeah, any of the used cdn links not loading. seems outdated

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar Any other mistake, you can think off. I have changed the links and tried. The new cdn links i am using are alive and fine. It still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CDN links looks outdated. This works just fine:

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello</h1>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
</script>
```

Ah, I think your issue in the updated code seems to be with babel link. It should be babel not browser.

So, for example, just replace:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/6.1.19/browser.min.js
```

With:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js
```

Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dahy047f/).

---

Here are the list of links through which you may consider using specific version:

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/react

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/react-dom

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/babel-standalone

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be an old version of React in your script which doesn't include the ReactDOM object. However with the latest React version and changing `ReactDom` to `ReactDOM` your code compiles fine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudfare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <h1>Hello world from the index form within HTML</h1>

    <div id="app1"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">
      ReactDOM.render(
        <h1>HELLLLLOO</h1>,
        document.getElementById('app1')
      );
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: ReactDOM is available in 0.14.X version of react

Comment: In that case something must be wrong with the library code he provided which is 0.14.X because i get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: ReactDOM is not defined` using his provided library link.

Comment: The CDN link aren't loading. Giving timeout

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I have updated the CDN links it still does not work. The links I am using now are alive and working. I have updated the question for your reference